# Fit a loess line in R on binary data

Tags: r, binary-data, loess

I'm trying to fit a loess line on a scatterplot of a binary outcome variable with a continuous predictor variable.

Here is the code I am using:

```
    lw1<-loess(y~x, data=df) 
    plot(y~x, data=df, pch=19, cex=0.1)
    lines(df$x, lw1$fitted, col='blue')
```

and this is the graph I get:
!https://bitbucket.org/heatherjbaldwin/akos_open/src/ec2a78d093e6cdf988434c03c1b7c7df145892ba/loessgraph1.png?at=master

I also tried ordering the x variable:

```
    j<-order(df$x)
    lines(df$x[j], lw1$fitted, col='blue')
```

And get this graph:
!https://bitbucket.org/heatherjbaldwin/akos_open/src/ec2a78d093e6cdf988434c03c1b7c7df145892ba/loessgraph2%28ordered_x%29.png?at=master

Here is the data: https://bitbucket.org/heatherjbaldwin/akos_open/src/ec2a78d093e6cdf988434c03c1b7c7df145892ba/loesscurvedata.txt?at=master

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ggplot2` and a `loess` smoother I get this :

```
ggplot(data=dat,aes(x,y)) + 
     geom_line() + 
     geom_smooth(method='loess')
```

[image]

But I think your a looking for a **classifier** here.